# How to developed Webpart that take argument run time(After deployed in sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint

I have developed one Active directory webpart that get uer information from Active Directory department wise( Department name is specific hard coded). i want to give specific department after deploying into sharepoint. is it possible and how. please give me  reference for the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own custom properties to a web part that can be configured at runtime using the web part pane.

[See this example](http://johnlivingstontech.blogspot.com/2008/07/sharepoint-web-part-custom-properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is of course correct. But if you need something completely runtime, you can always use the querystring parameters and access the page with the WP using parameters in the URL, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish